# Best way to deploy shared jar in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jar, shared-libraries, web-deployment, tomcat8

I have a app with 2 war, one has the webapp and the other is the api for externals. Both use the same library jar with the business logic.

I deploy remotely wars with tomcat nacen plugin, bit i don t know how deploy the jar in the shared folder.

In addition i am not sure that after deploy i must force wars to restart

What is the best way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just place the `.jar` file inside the `/lib` directory and the [classloader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) will pick it up and load it when you restart Tomcat.